# Python How to keep x lines after a regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am pretty new to Python. I have a bunch of articles in a txt files, all ending with the mention "Copyright". After this pattern is match I d like to keep a certain nber, x, of lines and copy them in another file.
I have tried the following code and a lot of variations (with issue on the index being out of the range) but I have an empty return.
Could you please help me ?
Thanks

```
with open("ILL 2013.txt",'r') as file:       
    with open('output.txt','w') as f:
        #lines=file.readlines()
        #match = re.search('Copyright', lines)
        #searchquery="Copyright"
        #try:
        for line in file:
            if re.search("copyright",line):
                i=file.index(line)
                for iline in range(i,i+2):
                    f.write(file[iline])
        print('done.')
        #except:
            #print('not in file.')
```

Comment: If you know that the copyright message is at the end of each file, could you instead just copy the last few lines and avoid the regex? One problem you might run into with your general approach here, even if you get it working is that you would have to be sure that none of the articles ever use the word 'copyright' in the actual text of the article...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if re.search("copyright", line):
    for _ in range(x):
        line = file.readline()
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not work I still got a blank output file.

Comment: Attach the file then... we'll try to figure it out.

Comment: How can i attach a file ... ?

Comment: Here is what I did and actually I get 10 times my copyright line but not the 10 lines after it.

Comment: # Import modules
from __future__ import division
import  re, pprint

def main():
    
    with open("ILL 2013.txt",'r') as file:       
        with open('output.txt','w') as f:
            #try:
            for line in file:
                if re.search("Copyright",line):                  
                    #line = file.readline()
                    for _ in range(10):
                        f.write(line)
        print('done.')
            #except:
                #print('not in file.')
        
if __name__ == "__main__": main()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad post, here is what I did :

## Import modules

from **future** import division
import  re, pprint

def main():

```
with open("ILL 2013.txt",'r') as file:       
    with open('output.txt','w') as f:
        #try:
        for line in file:
            if re.search("Copyright",line):                  
                #line = file.readline()
                for _ in range(10):
                    f.write(line)
    print('done.')
        #except:
            #print('not in file.')
```

if **name** == "**main**": main()